# How can I call method of entity in a repository querybuilder

Tags: symfony, query-builder

I have this scenario:
a entity Person, a repository for Person and a select form type.

I should take in my select form only active person.

In the entity there is a public method "isActive" that check if a Person have the permission to access in my private area. This method return true or false and is not a column in the db table, it is calculated.

I need to access this flag from my querybuilder in the Person repository.
Is it possible?
below the code of my querybuilder in the repository.

```
public function getQueryBuilderForEventRegistration()
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')->orderBy('e.surname', 'asc')->addOrderBy('e.name', 'asc');

    return $queryBuilder;
}
```

and the public method in the entity Person tha t i have to access:

```
public function getIsActive()
{
    if (empty($this->getUser()))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!$this->getUser()->isEnabled())
    {
        return false;
    }

    /* @var $service \Siderweb\SubscriptionBundle\Entity\UserService */
    foreach ($this->getUser()->getServices() as $service)
    {
        if (!$service->getIsExpired())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

and my type:

```
$builder->add('personExist', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'MyAppUserBundle:Person',
            'property' => 'name',
            'required' => false,
            'multiple' => false,
            'mapped' => false,
            'empty_value' => '-- New person --',
            'query_builder' => function(PersonRepository $repo) use ($options) {
                return $repo->getQueryBuilderForEventRegistration();
            }
        ))
```

as suggested I edit my repository like this:

```
 public function getQueryBuilderForEventRegistration(Company $company = null, Event $event = null, $emailFilter = null)
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')->orderBy('e.surname', 'asc')->addOrderBy('e.name', 'asc');

    $people = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->execute();
    $peopleToShow = array();

    foreach ($people as $person)
    {
        if ($person->getIsActive())
        {
            array_push($peopleToShow, $person);
        }
    }

    return $peopleToShow;
}
```

but now I don't know how to put this array in my typeForm. Any idea?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, but you can do that in your controller, and add the paramater to your function : getQueryBuilderForEventRegistration($param) and do what you want with param

Comment: How complex is your custom function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so you can't call entity method on the query builder, but you can on the query results. Doctrine will hydrate your entity objects with the data that is returned from the database.

Once you have your results you can call the isActive() method on the hydrated entities.

The way that you're trying to implement this (getting the query builder for the form), you will need an isActive column in your database table and add a 'where' clause like so:

```
public function getQueryBuilderForEventRegistration()
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->where('e.isActive', true)
        ->orderBy('e.surname', 'asc')
        ->addOrderBy('e.name', 'asc');

    return $queryBuilder;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer,
but once i have the result from my query builder how can i call the resulted filtered array in the type builder?

Comment: In a form, you can't do anything with the results, apart from build the query you require. Once you have your querybuilder object, you can call $queryBuilder->getResult() which will return an array of objects return. You can then loop through them and call the ->isActive() method on the object.

Comment: But if my QueryBuilder returns me back an array how can I put it into my typeform structure?

Comment: Your query builder will only return an array once ->find(), ->findBy() etc are called... If you want your form element results filtering by isActive, you're best adding an isActive column to your table, then you can build the criteria into the query builder.

Comment: The Active flag depends on several things, adding a column with this info force me to add a lot of listener in my app. Ooops I wrote querybuilder but I wanted to write repository. please check my edited question.  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to call a Custom PHP method a SQL query, so Doctrine's QueryBuilder does not allow that. You will need either to have `isActive` as a database field (or custom method), or to reproduce you `getIsActive` method with QueryBuilder conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the filter function to filter the array on the template.
In my case I have an entity that has a canBeProcessed method ( which depends on many things ).
So, when I want to show in the index method of the controller only those records that

"canBeProcessed" I use this :

{% for emitted_note in pagination|filter( emitted_note => emitted_note.canBeProcessed == true )  %}

```
        <tr><td>{{emitted_note.data}}</td><tr>
```

{% endfor %}

Here's the twig documentation.

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/filter.html

Regards.